# Cannot convert string to hex

Tags: python, string, hex

I'm trying to convert a string to hex on Python but I made something wrong.

On this site: http://string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx I got the follow converted code

> "60b6e02de9a758dbf43c0756f59e1d6558b46b462865a3b66d7922e8a2962175"

which works, but on my Python script I got

> "60c2b6c3a02dc3a9c2a758c39bc3b43c0756c3b5c5be1d6558c2b46b462865c2a3c2b66d7922c3a8c2a2e280932175".

The string on question is:

```
`¶à-é§XÛô<VõžeX´kF(e£¶my"è¢–!u
```

And the Python script used:

```
import binascii
x = '`¶à-é§XÛô<VõžeX´kF(e£¶my"è¢–!u'
a = x.encode('utf-8')
hex_bytes = binascii.hexlify(a)
print(hex_bytes)
```

Comment: The one conversion that is neither unclear nor wrong here is the hex. You asked for utf-8 and got it. Did you expect us to guess what the other one was? My guess is cp1252, which Windows tends to use for 8-bit text.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Yann Vernier suggested, [the webpage](http://string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx) appears to be encoding with
cp1252 before hexlifying:

```
import binascii

x = u'`¶à-é§XÛô<VõžeX´kF(e£¶my"è¢–!u'
hex_bytes = binascii.hexlify(x.encode('cp1252')) 
print(hex_bytes)
```

yields

```
60b6e02de9a758dbf43c56f59e6558b46b462865a3b66d7922e8a2962175
```